# Gui in java with textarea for Instance variables

Tags: java, oop, user-interface

I've been trying to makke a working GUI for the past week. I have attempted the grid bag layout and now the following. Howeverr I cannot get all the things I need working to be on there. Take the following code I have

```
public class testGUI extends JPanel {
  protected static double [] value;  
  JPanel jp = new JPanel();
  JTextArea jt = new JTextArea(10,40);

  public testGUI()
  {
JButton btn1 = new JButton("SportCar");
JButton btn2 = new JButton("Van");
btn1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
btn2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
jp.add(jt);
add(btn1);
add(btn2);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
for (int i=0; i<args.length;i++)
{   value[i]= Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
}
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(new testGUI());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
ButtonListener() {} 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("SportCar"))
{   Vehicle car1 = new SportCar(value[0],value[1],value[2]);
    System.out.println("You have made a new Sportcar");

}
else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Van"))
{   Vehicle car1= new Van(value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3]);
    System.out.println("You have made a new Van");

}
  }
}
```

I have made the listener but the two things I cannot do are create a text area in the GUI which displays the instance variables. And also the SportCar and the Van constructors require 3 and 4 user inputted numbers, this too I cannot do. Please help I have been stuck on GUI for too long. Thank you

Comment: what exactly is it that doesn't work? doesn't it give you the result you expect? do you get a compile time error? do you get a runtime error?

Comment: For example the value array is causing problems and I believe thats why what I have done so far doesnt compile.

Comment: "is causing problems". can you be more specific about this?

Comment: You have to instantiate the array before trying to put values in it. If you don't know how many elements it will have, use a List, not an array.

Comment: Ok I will trry that, could you help with providing text fields on the gui that show its private fields? Also, I meant compile time errors

Comment: I know you meant compile time errors, I have explained why. you get them. just add JTextFields or JLabels to the panel

Comment: Also, the array (list) is used in both static and non static methods. How can I avoid a compile time error?

Comment: by instantiating it. that it is used within both static and non-static methods is a bit dodgy, but shouldn't prevent working.

Comment: @Stultuske but there is some conflict between Static variable and non static methods and vice versa isnt there?

Comment: You could wrap your data structure (the array; although I'd suggest using a List) within a singleton pattern. It is more elegant than using a static field that is used throughout your code

Comment: There is no conflict. Just refer to your static field as testGui.value[i] if you're using it outside of it's "parent" class. Else the jvm would search vor value[] within your ButtonListner. And there is no such field so it gives an error.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet Thank you that helped, now I will try to do the text area myself. But most tutorials I find are for the user to input text. Could you tell me what to search for rather than "text area"? Thank you

Comment: If you want to display text (like an output) you could use the textArea or textfield and set it to not editable "jt.setEditable(false)". You could also use a JLabel to display your output

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet Thank you I will try that!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all. You should initialize your array. Thats done right before your loop with:

```
value = new double[args.length];
```

Also you should call your static array like so `testGui.value[i]` if you want to access it within another class than the one where you declared it. 
You might also think about using a List and using the Singleton Pattern if you have to access this data structure throughout many different classes.